# changing package variable in order to change decorator behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I have a package with the module `pymetrics.py`:

```
from .utils import minSample
MIN_SIZE = 10


@minSample(MIN_SIZE)
def inventory(df):
    '''for quantisation'''
    return len(df)
```

(and many other metrics with the same decorator)

...along with `utils.py`:

```
def minSample(sample=None):
    def decorator(method):
        @wraps(method)
        def f(*args, **kwargs):
            if len(args[0]) < sample:
                return None
            return method(*args, **kwargs)
        return f
    return decorator
```

Now, In my production code (outside of package) I want to change minimum sample size (MIN_SIZE) so that it will affect all the decorated functions: in specific case, I am fine having MIN_SIZE=0;

However, I can't get how to do so;

```
import pandas as pd
from package import pymetrics as mtr
mtr.MIN_SIZE = 0


test = pd.DataFrame({'price': [10, 20, 10], 'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']})

mtr.inventory(test)
>>> None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time the `import` line is done, all the functions have already been defined. It's already too late to change `MIN_SIZE`. What you *can* do, however, is change the way you define your decorator so that it can accept a change. For example, you could make it a class:

```
class minSample:
    MIN_SIZE = 10
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

In your `__call__` method, you can put all your decorator code, with `self.MIN_SIZE` and `self.function`. When you want to change `MIN_SIZE`, simply change the class variable:

```
minSample.MIN_SIZE = 0
```

In this way, the decorators are not attached to the original `MIN_SIZE`, but can be updated as many times as you want throughout the code. You can even update individual functions:

```
inventory.MIN_SIZE = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer above is absolutely legit, I've ended up using decorator with the additional parameter, as it seems to be more transparent

```
def min_sample(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def new_f(df, *args, min_size=2, **kw):
           if len(df) < min_size: return None
           else: return f(df, *args, **kw)
    return new_f
```